# Why is the character count wrong after first entry?

Tags: c, loops, character, counting

I have written a program in C to count characters input from stdin. I wanted to use a loop to allow more than one entry. (Note: I am new to programming.)

```
main()
{
    long nc;
    int c;
    int kc=1;
    for (kc=1;kc<=5;kc=kc+1)
    {
        nc=0;
        c= getchar();
        while(c != '0')
        {

        ++nc;
        c=getchar();
        }

        printf("%1d\n",nc);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

So basically as you would guess, the loop accepts 5 entries.

PROBLEM: When I enter `Sky0` the first result is all right, 3. But from then on, one is added to the count. That is entering `dame0` results in a count of `5`, `sit0` results in a count of `4` etc.

While trying to debug the problem using prinf at various stages, I realized that after the first result the code finds the end of the input, `0`, but enters the for loop NEVERTHELESS and waits for the next entry with `nc` as `1`. That leads to the error in corresponding outputs.

Please tell where I'm going wrong? And why is it entering the loop even after sensing `0`?

Greatly appreciate your help and time :)

Comment: `nc` gets set to `0` on each iteration of the `for` loop. The `while` loop will be terminated when the character literal `'0'` is found. I check what @aix stated and that is correct, see http://ideone.com/gw1ON for what I did. It shows the newline character forming part of the subsequent input.

Comment: Is it possible c == '0'? when c =='0' then while loop will be terminate. I have got c = -1 every time.

Comment: Are you talking slang? Please make some efforts while writing your questions and indenting the code. Else people won't waste time to read it.

Comment: hmjd: Thanks man!...Yea i corrected it, what a non professional way terminatin with a zero was neway...appreciate ure time :)

Comment: prasad g: It's not clear mate...

Comment: Seki: Hope that was for prasad g :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you press enter, that becomes a character too (value 0x1a), and it is returned by the `getchar` call outside the while loop.

You could do something like:

```
while (getchar() != '\n') nc++;
```

In that way you do not even need to use a 0 to mark the end of the string.